# Extjs combo box always showing the first element selected

Tags: extjs4

I am new to Extjs. I am facing this problem when I am trying to use combobox with a store that is populated through an AJAX call. I want the combobox to display the item that starts with the character typed in the combo box but the combobox is always showing the 1st item in the list.Here is my code,

```
Ext.define('fieldModel', {
        extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields : [ {
            name : 'name'
        },{
            name : 'value'
        }]
    });
    {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                id: 'startField',
                name: 'startField',
                style: 'margin-right:10px;',
                width: 230,
                fieldLabel: 'Field',
                labelAlign: 'top',
                displayField: 'name',
                valueField: 'value',
                triggerAction:'query',
                minChars:2,
                //forceSelection:true,
                //enableKeyEvents:true,
                minListWidth:150,
                //allowBlank:false,
                queryMode: 'remote',
                typeAhead: true,
                //hideTrigger: true,
                store:new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                    model: 'fieldModel',
                    //autoLoad: true,
                    //sortOnLoad : true,
                    //sortRoot: 'data',
                    proxy : {
                        type : 'ajax',
                        url: requesturl + '?action=getDate&itemid='+ preItemId,
                        reader : {
                            type : 'json',
                            root : 'data',
                        }
                    },
                    listeners :{
                        load : function( store, records, successful, operation, eOpts){
                            Ext.getCmp('startField').getStore().sort('name', 'ASC');
                        }
                    }
                }),
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change your listener to keypress or keyup event

keypress( Ext.form.field.Text this, Ext.EventObject e, Object eOpts )

This event only fires if `enableKeyEvents` is set to true.

```
listeners :{
        keypress : function( text, event, eOpts){
           Ext.getCmp('startField').getStore().sort('name', 'ASC');
        }
   }
```